# Background color not binding with a property

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I can't bind a background color to my property located in my code behind.

My property:

```
public Color SelectedColor
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedColor;
        }

        set
        {
            pdfViewerControl.AnnotationSettings.FreeText.TextColor = value;
            selectedColor = value;
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

My Button:

```
Button colorButton = new Button();
        colorButton.CornerRadius = 20;
        colorButton.BorderWidth = 2;
        colorButton.HeightRequest = 30;
        colorButton.WidthRequest = 30;
        colorButton.BindingContext = this;
        colorButton.SetBinding(Button.BorderColorProperty, new Binding("Value", source: SelectedColor));
        colorButton.SetBinding(Button.BackgroundColorProperty, new Binding("BackgroundColor", source: SelectedColor));
```

I tried different binding context but it doesn't work.

Both sections of code are on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your property is named `SelectedColor`, then you should use that as the binding path when creating the binding

```
colorButton.SetBinding(Button.BackgroundColorProperty, new Binding("SelectedColor"));
```

Comment: Ok that make sens now, I misunderstood the concept when I was reading this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings. Thank you !